# Error en Costo de Envío MercadoPago\Shipments

Tags: php7

Tengo un ecommerce con PHP de backend, el cual estoy intentando integrar con el checkout pro de Mercado Pago, a través del SDK de PHP.
Estoy teniendo dificultades para ingresar el costo del envío del producto.

---

```
$shipment = new MercadoPago\Shipments();
$shipment->mode = 'not_specified';
$shipment->cost = 1000;
```

---

```
$preference->shipments = $shipment;

var_dump($shipment):
object(MercadoPago\Shipments)#88 (12) { ["mode":protected]=> string(13) "not_specified" ["local_pickup":protected]=> NULL ["free_methods":protected]=> NULL ["cost":protected]=> string(6) "339.00" ["free_shipping":protected]=> NULL ["receiver_address":protected]=> NULL ["dimensions":protected]=> NULL ["default_shipping_method":protected]=> NULL ["_last":protected]=> NULL ["error":protected]=> NULL ["_pagination_params":protected]=> NULL ["_empty":protected]=> bool(false) } NULL
```

---

```
$preference->save();
```

---

Pero cuando carga la página me arroja el siguiente error:
"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ..\vendor\mercadopago\dx-php\src\MercadoPago\Generic\RecuperableError.php on line 30"

*RecuperableError.php (Archivo de SDK)*

```
namespace MercadoPago;

class RecuperableError {

    public $message = "";
    public $status = "";
    public $error = "";

    public $causes = [];

    function __construct($message, $error, $status) {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->error = $error;
    }

    public function add_cause($code, $description) {
        $error_cause = new ErrorCause();
        $error_cause->code = $code;
        $error_cause->description = $description;
        array_push($this->causes, $error_cause);
    }

    public function proccess_causes($causes){
        if(isset($causes['code']) && isset($causes['description'])){
            $this->add_cause($causes['code'], $causes['description']);
        }else{
            **foreach ($causes as $cause){**
                if(is_array($cause) && (!isset($cause['code']) && !isset($cause['description']))){
                    $this->proccess_causes($cause);
                }else{
                    $this->add_cause($cause['code'], $cause['description']);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->error . ": " . $this->message;
    }

}
```

Intenté de mil maneras pero no logré solucionarlo.

Me podrán ayudar?

Me disculpo cualquier mención incorrecta... es mi primer post.

Gracias!

Comment: Muestra el código donde esta el error, en ese .php linea 30... dice ser un foreach completo. Dice que el argumento entregado no es correcto.

Comment: Guardado. Gracias!

Comment: en donde compruebas que $causes  es un array antes de llegar a ese punto puedes hacer un dump de la variable para ver su tipo y contenido

Comment: Demás que es un warning, no un error. Le estás dando un argumento vacío al foreach.

Comment: var_dump($causes); --> NULL

Comment: eso quiere decir que el error esta antes de ese punto ... en que lugar armas el array $cause no esta armandoce o el resultado es una variable con valor null, te recomiendo aplicar ingenieria inversa para detectar el error de tu aplicacion o implementar un debugger como https://github.com/arcanisgk/BEH-Basic-Error-Handler o https://github.com/arcanisgk/BOH-Basic-Output-Handler que te facilitan la busqueda de este tipo de errores.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes presente un error de lógica y de comprobación de datos:

Según lo que describes el error es atribuible a que no validad la variable `$causes`.

El error de lógica es por la forma en que validas con `isset()`

Tu código debería ser así:

```
public function proccess_causes($causes){
    if(isset($causes['code']) && isset($causes['description'])){
        $this->add_cause($causes['code'], $causes['description']);
    }elseif($causes!=null && is_array($causes){
        foreach ($causes as $cause){
            if(is_array($cause) && (!isset($cause['code']) && !isset($cause['description']))){
                $this->proccess_causes($cause);
            }else{
                $this->add_cause($cause['code'], $cause['description']);
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Error del Sistema'.var_dump($causes);
        die;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Francisco. Con esto mitigo el error de la función, pero MP aún no funciona.

Comment: mira el problema inicial era corregir esto, si MP no funciona debes tener mas errores que depurar... si los encuentras y no puedes solucionarlo, create otro post con la informacion de aquel error...

Comment: te lo sugiero de esta forma por que no podemos jalar todo tu proyecto para revisarlo ni el tiempo para hacerlo. en el sitio nos vemos limitados a resolver errores puntuales y dar orientación, cuando tengas 100 puntos en tu perfil podrás entrar al chat y pedir ayuda en ese canal.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...", es por que espera del servidor [cause] =>array() y en su lugar la respuesta es [cause] => null.

te muestro el mensaje de error que viene del servidor.

```
Array
(
    [message] => invalid type (string) for field: shipments.cost    
    [error] => invalid_shipments.cost
    [status] => 400
    [cause] => 
)
```

Ahora, segun el mensaje se esta entregado el valor de costo como un string,y lo puedes ver en :

```
var_dump($shipment):
object(MercadoPago\Shipments)...["cost":protected]=> string(6) "339.00"...
```

Lo puedes solucionar con int_val() o floatval(), Tu código debería ser así:

```
$monto = floatval( 1000 ) ; 
$shipment = new MercadoPago\Shipments();
$shipment->mode = 'not_specified';
$shipment->cost = $monto;


introducir el código aquí
```

```
$monto = intval(180) ; 
$shipment = new MercadoPago\Shipments();
$shipment->mode = 'not_specified';
$shipment->cost = $monto;
```